# UISearchBar in UIToolBar doesn't become first responder

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

i have add with interface builder a UISearchBar in a UIToolBar, and then i have connect the UISearchBar with an IBOutlet in my class, and i have do this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

but the keyboard doesn't appear, i have to touch on the uisearchbar to let the keyboard appear, how i can do to let the keyboard appear on the uisearchbar when the view appear?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line in viewDidAppear.  Is self.mySearchBar nil?

Comment: Implement this in viewDidLoad method as well and check if that makes any difference.

Comment: self.mySearchbar is not nil, and if i put it in viewdidload doens't work...

Comment: have you declared in your view controller conforms to <UITextFieldDelegate> protocol in your interface file:
@interface YourClass : ... <UITextFieldDelegate>.. or in your Interface Builder? The ViewDidAppear is called? Put NSLog there..

Comment: also with the uitextfield delegate doesn't work, and yes the view did appear is called i put nslog and breakpoint...

Comment: Sorry.. You must use  <UISearchBarDelegate>

Comment: You can also control-drag from your UISearchBar to the FileOwner  - In the popup menu select delegate

Comment: i already have it, but nothing, doesn't work...bho